# Which framework is the best one to develop UI with multi-platform support, Windows, Linux, Android and iOS mobiles?

Tags: c#, linux, user-interface, frameworks, multiplatform

Which framework best suits to develop UI with multi-platform support - Windows, Linux, Android and iOS mobiles?

This app UI will communicate with .NET Web Server using API's.

I read some where, they suggested below links for Linux platform support.
https://github.com/GtkSharp/GtkSharp
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia

What I'm looking is common code base for all platform, which is best Framework which suits my requirement.

Comment: Android does not have all the Net Libraries that are in full version of Net.  So the reference is saying that you must use only Net Libraries that are available on Android for code to be compatible.